# Menu fixed on top with animate on Scroll event

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate

Sorry guys, I haven't enough knowledge about html, CSS So I need your help.

HTML structure is

### Slider (on Top)

### Menu    (Middle)

### Content (Bottom)

I want when I scroll down, Menu should come on TOP  with smooth animation and remain fixed on top, and When I scroll up, and Slider is going to visible  then only Menu should comes at its original place.

In short, I want animated slider like [**`Example link`**](http://www.chanel.com/en_US/).I have same structure of HTML. But I don't understand how it works.

I want your help by any ready js library or by simply suggestion using JQUERY.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mitulshah/bwNGL/)(In js fiddle I've use simple single image, but in reality I have slider)

Answer (score 0):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7tWDF/) will give you a start.

Move the cursor over to the image window, then use the up and down arrows.

There are hundreds of ways for you to do what you want. This one is very inelegant.

JS

```
$('.lowerscreen').hide();

$( document ).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 38 )
     {
      $('.lowerscreen').hide('slow');
      $('.upperscreen').show('slow');
      event.preventDefault();
      }
});
$( document ).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 40 )
     {
      $('.lowerscreen').show('slow');
      $('.upperscreen').hide('slow');
      event.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me some example only for scroll event ? If it is, it's lots of help to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll event". Your example page does not "scroll" it only uses up and down arrows

Comment: no it is on scroll. If I'm scroll down, slider is goes hide and menu animate to top and when scroll value is zero, menu goes to bottom and ans also slider will be display same as http://www.chanel.com/en_US/

Comment: Your "fashion link" only uses arrows. Your fiddle has a scroll bar, but there is no javascript, so there is no automatic scroll functionality. You need to be more specific in your question, and how you want it to work.